# jQuery using "subquery"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am moderately certain the answer has already been answered, my issue is I don't know what to even ask.

I am trying to dynamicly add already existing HTML divs by cloning them and changing the values, and I ran into an issue

HMTL :

```
    <div class="worldRow">
        <div class="worldProperties">Name</div>
        <div class="worldProperties worldName">World name</div>
        <div class="worldProperties">Population</div>
        <div class="worldProperties worldPopulation">50</div>
        <div class="worldProperties">Occupency</div>
        <div class="worldProperties worldOccupency">45%</div>
    </div>
```

Javascript :

```
function addWorld(data){
    var row = $('#fakeWorldList .worldRow').clone();
    row = $(row).attr('id',data.worldId);
    $(row).('.worldName').value('this will never work, halp.');
}
```

In my javascript, on the last row of my function, I am trying to set the div with the class "worldName" a new value, but I simply cannot figure how.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: try `$(row).find('.worldName').html('this will never work, halp.');`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to search for a child element

```
$(row).find('.worldName').text('this will never work, halp.');
```

Ex:

```
function addWorld(data){
    var row = $('#fakeWorldList .worldRow:first').clone();
    row = $(row).attr('id',data.worldId);
    $(row).find('.worldName').text('this will never work, halp.');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

.value is for input elements, you need to do

```
$(row).find('.worldName').html('this will never work, halp.');
```